# Join Datatables from a loop and merge in one Dataset

Tags: c#, asp.net, system.data.datatable

I have this requirement that the user request one or more partnumbers.And i need to display all the result in one Data Set

Ex: Request SerialNumbers with

```
PartNumber  Required Quantity
   A               2  
   B               1
   C               3
```

Code:

//Loop Request

```
foreach (DataRow a in request.Rows)
{
   //select top(Quantity) SerialNumber,PartNumber where PartNumber=@PartNumber
   var dt = new DataTable();
}
```

//1. PartNumber A

```
     SerialNumber  Partnumber
1                A
2                A
```

+

//2. PartNumber B

```
     SerialNumber  Partnumber
1                B
```

//3. PartNumber C

```
     SerialNumber  Partnumber
1                C
2                C
3                C
```

//Load to DataSet

And the result will be something like:

```
SerialNumber  Partnumber
1                A
2                A
1                B   
1                C
2                C
3                C
```

Thanks in Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please check below logic:

```
DataTable myDataTable = new DataTable();
        DataColumn PartNumber = new DataColumn("PartNumber");
        DataColumn RequiredQuantity = new DataColumn("RequiredQuantity");
        myDataTable.Columns.Add(PartNumber);
        myDataTable.Columns.Add(RequiredQuantity);

        DataRow dataRowPN1 = myDataTable.NewRow();
        DataRow dataRowPN2 = myDataTable.NewRow();
        DataRow dataRowPN3 = myDataTable.NewRow();


        dataRowPN1["PartNumber"] = "A";
        dataRowPN2["PartNumber"] = "B";
        dataRowPN3["PartNumber"] = "C";
        dataRowPN1["RequiredQuantity"] = "2";
        dataRowPN2["RequiredQuantity"] = "1";
        dataRowPN3["RequiredQuantity"] = "3";
        myDataTable.Rows.Add(dataRowPN1);
        myDataTable.Rows.Add(dataRowPN2);
        myDataTable.Rows.Add(dataRowPN3);
        int  i = myDataTable.Rows.Count;

        DataTable joinDataTable = new DataTable();
        DataColumn SerialNumber = new DataColumn("SerialNumber");
        DataColumn JoinPartNumber = new DataColumn("PartNumber");
        joinDataTable.Columns.Add(SerialNumber);
        joinDataTable.Columns.Add(JoinPartNumber);
        foreach (DataRow dr in myDataTable.Rows)
        {
            for (int count = 1; count <= Convert.ToInt16(dr["RequiredQuantity"]); count++)
            {
                DataRow joindataRow = joinDataTable.NewRow();
                joindataRow["SerialNumber"] = count.ToString().Trim();
                joindataRow["PartNumber"] = dr["PartNumber"].ToString().Trim();
                joinDataTable.Rows.Add(joindataRow);
            }
        }
        Response.Write(joinDataTable.Rows.Count);
```

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure what two tables you wish to join here and on what key but regadless of that, the simplest way will be to use LINQ to Dataset. For example,

```
var query = from a in table1
            join
            b in table2 
            on
            a.FkColumn = b.PKColumn select a,b;
```

Comment: agree.  if your question was of the form "how do i use this hammer to drive in this screw?", this answer is along the lines of "use a screwdriver instead".